# Access: Fill In value for empty Cell from same row different record

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Year|   Comp   |Value|
----------------------
2014|   XYZ    | 12  |          
2015|   XYZ    | 15  |      
2016|   XYZ    |Empty|      
2017|   XYZ    | 30  |     
2016|   ABC    |Empty|     
2017|   ABC    |Empty|  
2018|   ABC    | 12  |
```

I want to fill in the value of Company XYZ Year(Now) from Year+1 or whatever 
is available next +1 or +2 
Results should fill in like below :

```
Year: |2016| Comp|XYZ| Value|30|

Year: |2016| Comp|ABC| Value|12|
```

I have tried a using IFF, however some show up with Error , Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the recordset in VBA recording *Value* for each record.

If an empty *Value* is met, edit the record and update *Value* to the recorded value.

Continue until no more records.